# ITMS-90809 Apple Rejected iOS Apps

Tags: ios, objective-c, crashlytics, itms-90809

I have an App using Objective-C iOS application. 
My App was Rejecting with feedback ITMS-90809 which is about UIWebview.
I was using

```
grep -r "UIWebview" .
```

and got Crashlythic on the list, I also have to pod update the crashlytic to the latest version 3.14.
but, when i try to using grep again, the crashlytic still appear.
is there another option to fix that?
Thanks

Comment: If you really had updated to the latest, you'd be on 4.1.0: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/FirebaseCrashlytics.podspec

Comment: The dependency that I found is Crashlytic @Cœur, is it same as FirebaseCrashlytic?

Comment: you'll have the answer by visiting its website. Search for the pod "Crashlytics" on https://cocoapods.org, then click on [Site](http://try.crashlytics.com/) and it redirects you to https://firebase.google.com/products/crashlytics. This is to demonstrate that FirebaseCrashlytics is the newer version of Crashlytics.